# Google App Maker, how to create copy to clipboard function

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I'm trying to copy text from a text area to the clipboard with a button that runs the following script. 
I do get the alert of the text copied, but when I try to paste it somewhere the value was not copied.

```js
function copmycomment() {
/*get the text area*/
  var copyCo = app.pages.NewPage.children.Panel2.children.tao;

  /*select the text area*/

  copyCo.focus();

    /*copy the value*/

    document.execCommand("copy");

 alert("copied the text:" + copyCo.value);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Google App Maker, the TextArea widget is an object composed of two HTML elements; The **label** and the **input**. When you execute this line:

```
var copyCo = app.pages.NewPage.children.Panel2.children.tao;
```

You are actually selecting an appmaker object and not an HTML element that contains the text; Therefore, when this line of code is executed:

```
copyCo.focus();
```

You are not focusing the text you would like to copy and as a result the `document.execCommand("copy");` does not works.

In order to achieve what you need, please follow the below steps:

First, In a test page, insert a **TextArea** widget and below it a **Button** widget.
It should resemble something similar to this:
[image]

Then, add the following code to the **onClick** event handler of the button:

```
var textField = widget.parent.descendants.TextArea1.getElement().children[1];
textField.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
```

**Please Note:**
In the line `var textField = widget.parent.descendants.TextArea1.getElement().children[1];` the part `widget.parent.descendants.TextArea1` represents the path to the TextArea widget, so depending on how you do things, it might be different for you.

That should be all. Preview your app and the text should be copied to the clipboard. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful, tho it didn't work straightforward but I noticed that it failed when I had the text area disabled. Once I enabled it worked as expected. The Textarea is being populated with text from a query to a DB and the users are not suppost to edit the content that's why it was disabled.  I changed the textarea for an html element so displays the text and can't be edited but I still have problems understanding how this part works widget.parent.descendants.TextArea1.getElement().children[1] and so how to select the text in the html widget. Thank you for the help anyway!